# Помогите запустить example AngularJS который предлагается в WebSthorm как пример

Tags: angularjs, webstorm

Вообще ноль в  AngularJS и тому подобному. Сейчас попробовал запустить  Hello world но и это не вышло. Зацепило. Подскажите пожалуйста как это сделать? 
Создал новый проект  AngularJS в  WebStorm. Проект создался все отлично. Теперь запустить нужно. Скачал NodeJS сервер, добавил его в  WebStorm жму старт - показывает что все нормально запустилось, но в браузере ничего не открывается. Жму правой кнопкой мыши на index.html и выбираю показать в браузере - открывается,но только эта страница, по другим не переходит. В общем объясните пожалуйста, как запускать проект на AngularJS?

Comment: В правом верхнем углу в окне с кодом появляются иконки с изображениями браузеров. Их и надо запускать.

Comment: Спасибо КЭП)))))))))))))))))))))))) можете еще раз прочитать вопрос

Answer (score 1):

Если проект создавался из шаблона в **WebStorm**, тогда в корне проекта:

**npm install -g bower**

**bower install angular**

А потом запускаешь **index.html** и все работает.

Comment: Крутоооо!)))) во блин где бы я это узнал?)))) спасибо!